# SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, ssh, digital-ocean, puma

Trying to deploy a rails application to digital ocean following this tutorial:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma

but keep getting an error: 
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host xxx.xx.xx.xx: connection closed by remote host. Need help have been at this for the past four hours

```
>> cap production deploy:initial --trace  



    1 ↵
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke bundler:map_bins (first_time)
** Execute bundler:map_bins
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_rails_env
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env
** Invoke rvm:hook (first_time)
** Execute rvm:hook
DEBUG [5976e045] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rvm ] on xxx.xx.xx.xxx
DEBUG [5976e045] Command: [ -d ~/.rvm ]
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host xxx.xx.xx.xx: connection closed by remote host
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:16:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Net::SSH::Disconnect: connection closed by remote host
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:50:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in negotiate!'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in negotiate!'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:45:in `loop'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:45:in `block in negotiate!'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:43:in `loop'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:43:in `negotiate!'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:32:in `initialize'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:84:in `new'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:84:in `block in initialize'
/Users/andela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:74:in `timeout'
/Users/andela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:125:in `timeout'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:84:in `initialize'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:207:in `new'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:207:in `start'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `call'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `create_new_entry'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:22:in `checkout'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:187:in `with_ssh'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:137:in `block in _execute'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `tap'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `_execute'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:62:in `test'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-rvm-0.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/rvm.rake:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
EOFError: end of file reached
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:47:in `readpartial'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in negotiate!'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:45:in `loop'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:45:in `block in negotiate!'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:43:in `loop'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:43:in `negotiate!'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/server_version.rb:32:in `initialize'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:84:in `new'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:84:in `block in initialize'
/Users/andela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:74:in `timeout'
/Users/andela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:125:in `timeout'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:84:in `initialize'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:207:in `new'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:207:in `start'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `call'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `create_new_entry'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:22:in `checkout'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:187:in `with_ssh'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:137:in `block in _execute'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `tap'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `_execute'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:62:in `test'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/capistrano-rvm-0.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/rvm.rake:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => rvm:hook
```

Comment: Any luck with this one? Getting the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue recently, I think there is a mistake in the tutorial.

Here's what I changed.

`set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa) }`

I removed `.pub` from the `id_rsa`. And now I can deploy using the tutorial from Digital ocean.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to generate ssh-key from server and copy key to your GitHub.

Comment: i will but how sure are you ?